# New instance Foundation on setTimeout

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, zurb-foundation

I would lik programmatic use Sticky component of zurb Foundation framework, but asynchronous :

```
const sticky = new Foundation.Sticky($('.sticky'));
```

If i run this code, it work nice. But with setTimeout, it don't work :

```
setTimeout(() => {
  const sticky = new Foundation.Sticky($('.sticky'));
}, 2000);
```

You can test this on [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pexyOL).

Anyone can help me ? I don't know why my new instance don't work in async code.

Thank you !

Comment: Define *don't work*. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Yes, sorry. By say don't work, I'm talking about plugin on scroll (left sidebar will be fix). I've add codepen demo on my first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recalculate the points by calling the `_calc()` methode of `Sticky`:

```
setTimeout(() => {
   const sticky = new Foundation.Sticky($('.sticky'));
   $('.sticky').foundation('_calc', true);
}, 2000);
```

this worked in your codepen example.
I found the solution in the [Github issue tracker of zurb / foundation-sites](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/7899).